# How to get the KeyValue from QueryString and return string in specific string format

Tags: swift3

I am a newbie and need help.
I need to create a baseString from the below QueryString.
This baseString will look something like this in the end:

&ap=裕廊坊 心邻坊&oq=c# nunit mac&q=c# nunit mac

**QueryString :**

```
HTTPS://www.sky.com/api/v1/rest/level2/in-in/?q=c%23+nunit+mac&oq=c%23+nunit+mac&ap=裕坊%20邻坊
```

**Problem:**

How to get the KeyValue from the above QueryString

1) By getting all the components separated by "&" like below

--Keyvalue from the Query String:

q=c%23+nunit+mac&oq 
oq=c%23+nunit+mac 
ap=裕坊%20邻坊

```
I would use struct as I need to call the static func:

struct BaseString {

    static func createBaseString(authPrefix,signMethod,urlPath,nonce, timestamp,delimeter="&", bool sort= true, bool quote = false) -> String? {
        var dict = [String:String]()
        let url = NSURL(string: urlPath)

        var keyValues = url.query?.componentsSeparatedByString("&")

        //-(1)- adding keyValue into Dictinary 
        dict.??

        //-- how to add the data below?
        //- after (1) : Add other key value into same Dictionary
        dict Add(authPrefix + "_timestamp", timestamp);
        dict.Add(authPrefix + "_nonce", nonce);
        dict.Add(authPrefix + "_signature_method", signMethod);
        dict.Add(authPrefix + "_version", "1.0");

        var return_format:String 

        if quote == true{
            //-- create a baseString 
            sort the Dictionary
            return_format = "&" + url + "&" +Dictionary.ToString()
            (format: String = "q ="V1" "  the value with double quote)
        }else{
            //-- create a baseString 
            sort the Dictionary
            return_format = Dictionary.ToString()
            (format:Strig = " q=v2")
        }

        var baseString = return_format
        return baseString

    }
}
```

Thanks. your help is much appreciated.

Comment: Please clarify the question, what is the expected output format? Is this what you want? `["q=c#+nunit+mac", "oq=c#+nunit+mac", "ap=裕坊 邻坊"]` Or you just want to remove the URL encoding to get a non-URL encoded string  like this? `https://www.sky.com/api/v1/rest/level2/in-in/?q=c#+nunit+mac&oq=c#+nunit+mac&ap=裕坊 邻坊`

Comment: So happy to know you can help. This is the sample expected return base string : POST&https://www.sky.com/api/v1/rest/level2/in-in/&ap=裕廊坊 心邻坊&apex_l2_ig_app_id=loadtest-pvt-4Swyn7qwKeO32EXdH1dKTeIQ&apex_l2_ig_nonce=-4080538304832528027&apex_l2_ig_signature_method=SHA256withRSA&apex_l2_ig_timestamp=1503992930788&apex_l2_ig_version=1.0&oq=c# nunit mac&q=c# nunit mac

Comment: So do you have the query parameters stored as non-URL encoded strings and you want to generate a proper URL/NSURL using those query parameters?

Comment: First: I need to get KeyValue from the Query String and store it in dictionay. 2nd) Add additional items into the same dictionary like:  dict Add(authPrefix + "_timestamp", timestamp); 3rd). I want to generate a string like above string (after your first question) : POST&sky.com/api/v1/rest/level2/in-in/&ap=裕廊坊 心邻坊&apex_l2_ig_app_id=loadtest-pvt-4Swyn7qwKeO32EXdH1dKTeIQ&‌​apex_l2_ig_nonce=-40‌​80538304832528027&ap‌​ex_l2_ig_signature_m‌​ethod=SHA256withRSA&‌​apex_l2_ig_timestamp‌​=1503992930788&apex_‌​l2_ig_version=1.0&oq‌​=c# nunit mac&q=c# nunit mac

Comment: yes, you are right. When I get KeyValue from QueryString, I need to remove the encoded URL like q=c%23+nunit+mac&oq ,oq=c%23+nunit+mac  to oq‌​=c# nunit mac&q=c# nunit mac and store in Dictionary. After this, I will add addtional item into the same dictionary.

Answer (score 0):

You can get Key-Value dictionary from your URL's query items with the help of URLQueryItem class, like this

```
let urlString = "https://www.sky.com/api/v1/rest/level2/in-in/?q=c%23+nunit+mac&oq=c%23+nunit+mac&ap=裕坊%20邻坊"
let encodedUrlString = urlString.addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters: .urlQueryAllowed)!

let items = URLComponents(string: encodedUrlString)?.queryItems
var keyValues: [String: String] = [:]
items?.forEach{
    item in
    keyValues[item.name] = item.value
}
print(keyValues)
//["q": "c%23+nunit+mac", "ap": "裕坊%20邻坊", "oq": "c%23+nunit+mac"]
```

Hope this will help you.
If you need to obtain Query substring from your url string, you need to create URL from it and get query.

```
guard let url = URL(string: encodedUrlString) else {
    fatalError()
}
let queryString = url.query!
print(queryString.removingPercentEncoding)
//q=c%23+nunit+mac&oq=c%23+nunit+mac&ap=裕坊%20邻坊
```

If you need to add new components to your query,

```
var components = URLComponents(string: encodedUrlString)
let item = URLQueryItem(name: "NEWVKEY", value: "NEWVALUE")
components?.queryItems?.append(item)

let url = components?.url
let resultString = url?.absoluteString
//or
let resultString2 = url?.absoluteString.removingPercentEncoding
```

The idea is to use URL processing abilities of Swift standard library. Please check the documentation of URL, URLComponents, URLQueryItem structs. Don't write string processing code, manipulate URLs instead.

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/url
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/urlcomponents
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/urlqueryitem

Comment: This is good. How to add the additional item after items in the query string? like the one I mentioned above After (1).

Comment: @MilkBottle updated answer with sample of adding new query item

Comment: Your solution ok but 1) I need to get keyValue from the Query string, decode the Value, store the KeyValue in Dictionary 2) Add the additional items into the same dictionary 3) Sort the dictionary 4) Generate a string base on this format  return_format = "&" + url + "&" + Dictionary.ToString(). how to output the sorted items in Dictionary. Thanks